# Changing the shape of convolution kernels in keras or tflearn using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, convolution, tflearn

I was wondering if there is a way to change the shape of convolution kernels in keras or tflearn using tensorflow backend.

My objective is to test if shape of conv. 2d kernels affects the classification accuracy. That is if using circular, triangular or any other shape other than the default square kernels affect classification accuracy.

Keras and tflearn documentation does not help, any resources on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there are out of the box to use non rectangular shaped convolutions... You probably can do it in by manually resetting particular parts of the filter to 0 after each training step so that the filter would look like a circle, triangle, etc.. but might need to be careful about other nuances such as how to do padding.

Comment: Hi Gerges Dib, thanks for the information, will write a custom script, keeping padding in mind.